# Финансовый сервис с API международных массовых выплат / денежных переводов

Tags: платежи, интернет-эквайринг

Есть приложение, нужно принимать платежи (подписка на цифровые продукты) и затем распределять их между вендорами (расщепление платежей, или массовые выплаты, или что-то похожее) через API на карту (кошелек) пользователей из разных стран СНГ и Европы. Важно что бы сервис поддерживал именно формат международных переводов.

Может кто имел опыт с такими сервисами и может что-то предложить? Перерыл много СНГ-шных платежек, европейских, американских, у всех если и есть расщепление/массовые выплаты, то только в пределах одной страны. Или такое невозможно и я ищу то чего нет в природе?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: страйп?________

Comment: Страйп не работает в СНГ